# Connect an Authenticator App with Heroku results in "That code is invalid or expired. Try another."

Tags: heroku

When I try to log in to my Heroku account It mandates me to connect an authenticator app to generate an OTP, I try to Scan the QR with the DUO app however when I enter the generated code it says "That code is invalid or expired. Try another."
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried copying the code (secret key) and entering it manually into the authenticator application? You could also try clearing the 2FA application's cache, force closing the 2FA app or restarting the device itself. 

Remember that the codes are time-based (TOTP), so any issue with the internal clock on either device can cause problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support.

Comment: I tried with their Sales Force authenticator and it worked, however, I think there was an issue in their service of authenticating with other authenticating apps

Comment: @Chris no need friend
I just asked here to see if it's a known issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with their Sales Force authenticator and it worked, however, I think there was an issue in their service of authenticating with other authenticating apps